# C UDP server sending back a var to client

Tags: c, udp

I have a working client/server implementation in UDP in C, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the server to send a variable back to the client.

This is because the client sends X packets in 60 seconds, and the server will successfully receive Y packets.  I want the server to return the Y variable to the client so that it can do some calculations that the user can see (packets lost, bps, etc...).

However, is it possible for the server to simply use sendto() and the client use recvfrom()?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. On the server side extract clients address and use it:

```
 n = recvfrom(sockfd,msg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
 sendto(sockfd,msg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
```

On the client's side: left as an exercise for the reader.